# Icon not showing in searchbar in iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I just see a question mark icon where my search icon should be. Also get Unrecognised font for my other fonts.

```
  <SearchBar
                round
                containerStyle={{
                    borderTopWidth: 0,
                    borderBottomWidth: 0
                }}
                inputStyle={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}
                inputContainerStyle={{
                    borderRadius: 5,
                    backgroundColor: "white"
                }}
                icon={{
                    type: "fontAwesome",
                    color: "#86939e",
                    name: "fa-search"
                }}
                onSubmitEditing={this.onSubmitEdit}
                searchIcon={{ size: 18 }}
                onChangeText={text => this.SearchFilterFunction(text)}
                onClear={text => this.SearchFilterFunction("")}
                placeholder="Type Here..."
                value={term}
            />
```

Aswell as my serahc icon not appearing, I cannot get my fonts to show using:

```
  menuText: {
    fontSize: 15,
    color: "#fff",
    opacity: 1,
    fontFamily: "lato-regular",
    textTransform: "uppercase"
  }
```

I have linked the package, and copied the font file into xcode.

All my of my fonts appear under `Resources` in xcode. How can I display my icon?

I have my fonts in info.plist:

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>Lato-Regular.ttf</string>
    <string>Lato-Light.ttf</string>
    <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
    <string>Lato-Bold.ttf</string>
    <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
    <string>Lato-Black.ttf</string>
    <string>Lato-BlackItalic.ttf</string>
    <string>Lato-BoldItalic.ttf</string>
    <string>Lato-Hairline.ttf</string>
    <string>Lato-HairlineItalic.ttf</string>
    <string>Lato-Heavy.ttf</string>
    <string>Lato-HeavyItalic.ttf</string>
    <string>Lato-Italic.ttf</string>
    <string>Lato-LightItalic.ttf</string>
    <string>Lato-Medium.ttf</string>
    <string>Lato-MediumItalic.ttf</string>
    <string>Lato-Semibold.ttf</string>
    <string>Lato-SemiboldItalic.ttf</string>
    <string>Lato-Thin.ttf</string>
    <string>Lato-ThinItalic.ttf</string>
    <string>SpaceMono-Regular.ttf</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
const myIcon = <Icon name="rocket" size={30} color="#900" />;
```

use myIcon in your code.

Comment: I cant get any of my fonts to show, I've edited my original post

Answer (score 0):

If you're using react-native-vector-icons, check this https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/ to find your icons

The name is not *fa-search*, but just *search*

Comment: Still not working, Ive edited my question with more details